# C# Winforms - bind textbox to array element from class

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, arraylist, data-binding

I'm currently trying to bind an array element from a class to a text box without success.

```cs
class Test{
   ...
   string[] toto = new string[]{"element1"};
}

Test test;
void form_load()
{
   test = new Test();
   textBox1.DataBinding.Add("Text", test, "toto(0)");
}
```

(I tried as discussed here : [Winforms Databinding to element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056687/winforms-databinding-to-element-in-array))

But I get :

> `System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column
>   Requires(0) on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'`

If I bind it like this:

```cs
checkBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", config.Requires[0], ""));
```

It works but I can't implement INotifyPropertyChanged for updating the form on change perform by the code.

Does anyone have any idea?

Edit: After binding, the form should be updated when the element of the array is updated.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, [but this answer binding a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44459463/3585500) passes an event argument as well.

Comment: [data binding a control to an element of an array at specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315007/3110834)

Comment: @ourmandave doesn't work :/.

Comment: @RezaAghaei working but it doesn't update on the form when I edit the value in code. I don't know how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged there :(.

Comment: It means an array of string is not a good data structure for you.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes a BindingList is solving the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59633654/12530707 Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite possibly there is a better way to do this, but what you could do is create an instance of `BindingSource` for each element in the array, set the `BindingSource.Position` property, then set that as the binding for the `TextBox`.

**Edit: Made the Data Binding 2-way... changing the value in the control updates the object, changing the value from the object changes the control.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
   public class Foo
   {
      public Foo()
      {
         Items = new BindingList<string>();
      }

      public IList<string> Items { get; private set; }
   }

   static class Program
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// The main entry point for the application.
      /// </summary>
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

         _dataSource.Items.Add("Value");
         _dataSource.Items.Add("Value 2");
         _dataSource.Items.Add("Value 3");

         var frm = new Form();

         var flp = new FlowLayoutPanel
         {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown
         };

         for (int i = 0; i < _dataSource.Items.Count; i++)
         {
            var bs = new BindingSource(_dataSource, "Items");
            bs.Position = i;
            var tb = new TextBox();
            tb.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "");
            flp.Controls.Add(tb);
         }
         frm.Controls.Add(flp);

         var btn = new Button()
         {
            Text = "Show Object's Values",
            Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
         };
         btn.Click += btn_Click;
         frm.Controls.Add(btn);

         var btn2 = new Button()
         {
            Text = "Change Object's Values",
            Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
         };
         btn2.Click += btn2_Click;
         frm.Controls.Add(btn2);

         Application.Run(frm);
      }

      static void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _dataSource.Items.ToArray()));
      }

      static void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         var rng = new Random();
         for (int i = 0; i < _dataSource.Items.Count; i++)
         {
            var b = new byte[8];
            rng.NextBytes(b);
            _dataSource.Items[i] = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
         }
      }

      static Foo _dataSource = new Foo();
   }
}
```

Comment: this way to set the position is definitively more clear than described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325943/12530707. But the problem of "I change the value in my code and it doesn't update on form" still remains :/.

PS: from where is coming the `_dataSource` variable in your second code?

Comment: `_dataSource` is a static field on the `Program` class declared right before the closing curly brace of the `Program` class. `static Foo _dataSource = new Foo()`.

Comment: I made an edit to make the data binding two way by changing the type of `Foo.Items` to `IList` so I could use an indexer to change the values, then setting it to an instance of `BindingList<string>` instead of `List<string>` in the constructor for `Foo`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, you encapsulate the values in a BindingList element that probably already implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Perfect! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property as follows:

```
private string _element1;
public string Element1
{
  get
  {
    return _element1;
  }
  set 
  {
   element1 = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Element1));
  }
}
```

Set it as: `Element1 = config.Requires[0];`
And then use it to set the TextBox as follows: `checkBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", Element1, ""));`

Comment: Yes that is working but there is not another way cleaner than creating a properties for each value of my array? With an array of 100 value would involve to create 100 properties :/.